Why not work properly Auto-Login custom function in Wordpress?
Below mention custom function I used for Auto-Login after gravity form registration submit. After success form submission I checked debug log. It has "User is logged in: xxxxxx". I think it's mean logging process was succeeded. But I checked in site It's like not logged in. Logging button not changed to Logout. When I click Loggin button it's redirect again to login form. Please explain what's the issue & how to fix it.
// Hook into the Gravity Forms User Registration process
add_action('gform_user_registered', 'auto_login_after_registration', 10, 4);

function auto_login_after_registration($user_id, $config, $entry, $password) {
    // Log the user in
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);

    // Ensure the global $current_user is set
    global $current_user;
    $current_user = get_userdata($user_id);

    // Debugging: Verify user login status
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        error_log('User is logged in: ' . $current_user->user_login);
    } else {
        error_log('User login failed.');
    }
    exit;
}


Do you have full error reporting and display turned on? I’m wondering if there’s a “headers already sent” warning.

Why the exit statement? Are you sure the cookies are being sent to the remote client?
